# "Official" providers of topographic maps per country

Tags: hiking, maps, resources, topographical-maps

If I want to go to some contry, with no specific region in mind yet, I often have trouble to get good topographical information for hiking beforehand.  I usually find it rather difficult to discover by quick Googling, especially if I don't speak the local language.

But in many countries, at least in Europe, there is some kind of official institution which publishes map data and/or series of detailed topographic maps covering the whole country (or most of it), suitable for outdoor purposes.  Often these instututions are related to surveying, cadastral registration, or the military.

What are these official institutions per country, and what do they provide? If there is no such institution, what is the de-facto standard map provider in that country (which means: (almost) full coverage, organized series, used by "everyone and the alpine association", etc.)?

---

<sub>This is a self-answered "big list" question, discussed [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/15579).  If you have something to add, please edit the CW answer.  Stick to the official institutions or their de-facto alternatives -- *not* just every publisher producing maps.</sub>

Comment: Let's leave this open, the alternative is one question per country, and I don't think anyone wants 30+ very similiar questions when we can put all the information in one place

Comment: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/list-question-about-paper-map-series-providers-per-country?cb=1

Comment: You mean it should fullfill all of the *(almost) full coverage, organized series, used by everyone and the alpine association* that might be impossible. In Czechia we have several full coverage series by different providers. None is used by everyone, obviously... One of the providers is the tourist club though, if you count that as an "alpine" association.

Comment: Yeah, that was hyperbolic... but if some series has the same status as official providers elsewhere , and no more authoritative providers are available, it probably counts. Austria's ÖK50 are almost ideal in that sense, but we already have some countries with multiple alternatives (eg. Karttakeskus and Calazo, which are both private).

Comment: Not an "official" provider, but have you tried using Google Maps in [Terrain mode](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/bJl-be4Nwrg)? You have to be zoomed in pretty far to see contour lines, and in some places they are missing or hard to see if there are a lot of overlapping roads, but it might still be useful. [Here is an example.](https://www.google.com/maps/@-3.0676053,37.3670631,14.96z/data=!5m1!1e4)

Comment: I have, but it's not really useful for hiking, at least in Europe, since footpaths in nature areas are seldom included. OpenStreetMap I find pretty good in well-mapped areas. But both are rather besides the point here.

Comment: This would be incredibly useful in Japan

Answer (score 29):

## Europe

- **Austria**: The [*Bundesamt für Eich- und Vermessungswesen*](http://www.bev.gv.at/portal/page?_pageid=713,1604790&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL) (BEV, "Federal bureau for metrology and surveying") publishes the [ÖK50](http://www.amap.at/BLATTKM50/Blattuebersicht_KM50.html) series in scale 1:50000, covering the whole country.  Each map has a four-digit code, and for each (blue) ÖK50 map, there are two (green) ÖK25 maps in 1:25000 for the east and west half carrying the same number (*XXXX-Ost* and *XXXX-West*).  The maps are available in larger bookstores.  Marked trails and huts are indicated on the maps.  There's an [online viewer](http://www.austrianmap.at) for all their data.  The alpine association (ÖAV) also has a [series](https://www.alpenverein.at/portal/berg-aktiv/karten/uebersichten/alpen.php) of hiking maps for the alps, produced in cooperation with the BEV and the German alpine association (see Germany).
- **Belgium**: The [*Nationaal Geografisch Instituut*](http://www.ngi.be/NL/NL0.shtm)/[*Institut géographique national*](http://www.ngi.be/FR/FR0.shtm) has [multiple series](http://www.ngi.be/NL/NL1-1.shtm) of non-congruent, numbered maps covering the country, called *topo10*, *topo20*/*25* (blue), and *topo50* (red).  The latter two include marked trails.
- **Denmark**, including Faroe Islands and Greenland (also Sweden): [ScanMaps](https://www.scanmaps.dk/?___store=website_engelsk). Many different scales, ages and media as well as customized, personal maps printed and sent to you.
  The official government institution for Geo-data links to this (commercial) site for printed maps. Topographic, Digital maps are available for download as TIFF images (for free); resolutions 1:25.000 - 1:1.000.0000 at [kortforsyningen.dk](https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/content/geodataprodukter?field_korttype_tid_1=439) (site is unfortunately only in Danish)
- **Finland**: [*Maanmittauslaitos*](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en) (MML, "National land survey") doesn't itself provide a series of paper maps, but their data is [available online](https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/?lang=en) with tools for buying on-demand printed and PDF maps.  Furthermore, they provide for free high-resolution scans of [old printed map series](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/e-services/old-printed-maps).  There is, however, the GIS company [*Karttakeskus*](http://www.karttakeskus.fi/about-us/?lang=en), who have a series of numbered and congruent [topographical maps](https://www.karttakauppa.fi/en/products/productgroup/2062/outdoors) (*maastokartta*) in 1:50000 and 1:25000, covering the country.  In outdoor shops you'll find [Calazo](https://www.calazo.fi/product-category/kartat/) maps, which cover some national parks and famous trails.
- **France**: The [*Institut national de l’information géographique et forestière*](http://www.ign.fr/) (IGN) publishes [*Cartes de randonnée*](https://ignrando.fr/boutique/cartes/randonnee-france.html) with a [*Serie bleue*](https://ignrando.fr/boutique/cartes/randonnee-france.html?ign_serie=1217) of 1:25000 maps of all regions.  Marked trails are indicated.
- **Germany**: There is an [official system](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topografische_Karte#Amtliche_topografische_Karten_in_Deutschland) of *Topographische Karten* ("topographical maps" -- TK, or nowadays DTK for *Digitale Topographische Karten*) in several scales with congruent and numbered sheets, but it is somewhat decentralized.  The interesting scales, TK25 and TK50, are managed and published by the respective federal states' surveying agencies.  They can be bought at the state agencies (eg. [Niedersachsen](https://www.lgln.niedersachsen.de/geodaten_karten/topographische_karten_uebersichtskarten/); sometimes, printed on demand) or at bookshops.
  For hiking in the German alps, there is a [series of maps published by the alpine association](https://www.alpenverein.de/Huetten-Wege-Touren/Karten/Kartenuebersichten/).
- **Greece**: [*Γεωγραφική Υπηρεσία Στρατού*](http://web.gys.gr)  (Γ.Υ.Σ., "Hellenic Military Geographical Service") does have a website (optimized for IE 6 :)) with a [shop](http://eshop.gys.gr/OA_HTML/ibeCZzpHome.jsp?language=US) where maps of different scales can be bought. As far as I understand, there is a grid of numbered 1:5000 topographical maps over the whole country, and some other named maps in more usual scales are available; for selection, they have an [interactive map](http://web.gys.gr/GeoSearch_EN/).
- **Hungary**: The [*Department of Geodesy, Remote Sensing and Land Offices*](https://www.ftf.bfkh.gov.hu/portal_en/) has official [topographic maps](https://www.ftf.bfkh.gov.hu/portal/index.php/termekeink/terkepek), but they are not free (and their site has an invalid certificate). [*turistautak.hu*](http://turistautak.hu/) is a non-profit portal which has a community-sourced [interactive map](http://terkep.turistautak.hu/) with marked trails and other outdoors info. When looking for printed maps, the series by [*Cartographia*](http://www.cartographia.hu/) and [*Szarvas térképek*](https://www.map.hu/) are the most widely used ones.
- **Iceland**: [*Landmælingar Íslands*](https://www.lmi.is/en/),
  the National Land Survey of Iceland, doesn't itself publish maps,
  but have their data [viewable online](http://kortasja.lmi.is/en/).  However, there are printed hiking maps with blue cover, which you will
  find,
  outdoor shops and tourist infos.  They are published by [*Mál og
  Menning*](https://www.bmm.is/), a book shop in Reykjavík.  These maps don't cover the whole
  of Iceland, but only some "interesting" regions (eg. Laugavegur), in varying scales (usually 1:50000 or 1:100000), and show marked trails.
- **Ireland**: The [*Ordnance Survey Ireland*](https://www.osi.ie) is Ireland's national mapping agency. They are the responsible authority for all maps relating to Ireland. They offer [road maps](https://www.osi.ie/products/tourist-leisure/), [professional mapping data for businesses](https://www.osi.ie/products/professional-mapping/), and [maps for the outdoors](https://www.osi.ie/products/tourist-leisure/#adventure).
- **Italy**: The [Istituto Geografico Militare](https://www.igmi.org/) (IGMI, "Military Cartographic Institute") has several series in different scales, which one can [view and buy](https://www.igmi.org/geoprodotti) from their website.
- **Luxembourg**: [Le Géoportail National Du Grand-Duché De Luxembourg](http://map.geoportail.lu/communes/?lang=en) provide the various maps for Luxembourg. You can find them in various scales, such as [1:20000](http://map.geoportail.lu/communes/Luxembourg/topo_20k?lang=en), [1:250000](http://map.geoportail.lu/communes/Luxembourg/topo_250k?lang=en) and [1:5000](http://map.geoportail.lu/communes/Luxembourg/topo_5k?lang=en). You can print the maps and modify them them online. The maps are available in English, German, French and Luxembourgish.
- **Netherlands**: [*Topografische Kaart Nederland van het Kadaster*](https://www.kadaster.nl/-/topografische-kaart).
  The maps are readily available in 1:25000 and 1:50000 scale, as the basic map and with specialist additions like for cycling or walking, (also) from other publishers. Other scales are available as well.
- **Norway**: [*Kartverket*](https://kartverket.no/en/), the Norwegian mapping authority, doesn't provide a (paper) map series, but all their data is [available online](https://kartverket.no/en/data/Open-and-Free-geospatial-data-from-Norway/), including a [map viewer](http://www.norgeskart.no).
  However, there are two series published by [*Nordeca*](https://nordecakonsument.com/vare-kartserier/), which are [recommended by DNT](https://english.dnt.no/maps/) (the Norwegian alpine association) and available their stores. The [Norge series](https://forhandlere.nordeca.com/norge-serien) covers the country in scale 1:50000, while [Turkart](https://www.kartbutikken.no/turkart-serien) are developed in cooperation with DNT and come in several scales for "interesting regions".  The latter include marked trails and huts.
- **Spain**: The [*Instituto Geográfico National*](https://www.cnig.es/buscarArtsMenu.do) (IGN) publishes a [*Mapa Topográfico Nacional*](https://www.cnig.es/buscarArtsMenu.do) series in two scales, MTN25 and MTN50. Each MTN50 map has a number (*X*) and is divisible into 4 MTN25 maps (*X-1* to *X-4*). Both series are [also available in electronic form](http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/catalogo.do?Serie=MAMOV).
- **Sweden**: [*Lantmäteriet*](https://www.lantmateriet.se) is the "official" mapping agency. They provide 1:50000-scale topographic maps (*Terrängkartan*) for most of the country, except the mountains in the northwest which are covered by the 1:100000-scale *fjällkartan*. There also some smaller-scale maps. However, their production of paper maps will cease this summer. 50k and 10k-maps are [available as PDF](https://www.lantmateriet.se/kartutskrift), and the data corresponding to the 50k maps is available as open data.
- **Switzerland**: [*Swisstopo*](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/), the Swiss federal office of topography, provide multiple (numbered and congruent) series.  For one, there are the [national maps](https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/maps/national) in [1:25000](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/content/swisstopo-internet/en/home/products/maps/national/lk25/_jcr_content/contentPar/tabs_copy_copy_copy/items/dokumente_publikatio/tabPar/downloadlist_copy_co/downloadItems/273_1466760668856.download/blueb25.pdf) ("brown" series) and [1:50000](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/content/swisstopo-internet/en/home/products/maps/national/lk50/_jcr_content/contentPar/tabs_copy_copy_copy_/items/dokumente_publikatio/tabPar/downloadlist_copy_co/downloadItems/273_1466760668856.download/blueb50.pdf) ("green" series) covering the whole country.  Switzerland has a [huge network of waymarked hiking trails](https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege&layers_visibility=false,false,false,true&layers_timestamp=18641231,,,), so swisstopo also publishes a "yellow series" of [hiking maps](https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/maps/leisure_maps/hiking_maps) in 1:33333 and 1:50000 scales, which use the 1:50000 base map with the hiking trails marked in colour. Unfortunately, swisstopo itself does not publish a 1:25000 series showing the hiking trails, but various third party providers do. Such maps can generally be found at local bookshops and tourist offices.  The whole data are also viewable for free [online](https://map.geo.admin.ch), including option to download a tile for offline use and extensive geoinformational data.
- **UK**: The [*Ordnance Survey*](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/) publishes [two series](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/maps.html) covering England, Wales, Scotland and Isle of Man: *Explorer* in scale 1:25000 (numbered *OL* + digits), and *Landranger*  (just digits) in scale 1:50000.  Their sheets are not necessarily congruent.

  [*Ordnance Survey of Northern Ireland*](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/campaigns/ordnance-survey-of-northern-ireland) cover the country at 1:50000 (*Discoverer* series) and popular recreational areas at 1:25000 (*Active* series).

  [*Harvey Maps*](https://www.harveymaps.co.uk/) is an alternative mapping provider offering 1:25000 and 1:40000 maps of the main hiking areas. OS and Harvey maps differ in style and both are widely sold in the UK.

## North America

- **Canada**: [National Topographic System Maps](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/maps/9767)
- **United States**: The official publisher of topographical maps in the United States in the [United States Geological Survey](https://nationalmap.gov/ustopo/index.html). They have both 15 and 7.5 minute maps as well as [historical topographical  maps](https://nationalmap.gov/historical/index.html). It is possible to [download](https://store.usgs.gov/map-locator) the maps for free, or some outdoor shops will sell the paper maps.

## Oceania / Australia

- **Australia**: while the government has a [dedicated webpage](https://www.australia.gov.au/information-and-services/business-and-industry/science-and-technology/maps-and-mapping) with several resources, [HEMA maps](https://www.hemamaps.com/) is the provider used for navigation and orientation. It frequently appears as the maps to be used in insurance polices and car-rental agreements.
- **New Zealand**: The government in the form of [Land Information New Zealand](https://www.linz.govt.nz) supplies [topographic maps](https://www.linz.govt.nz/land/maps/topographic-maps), [aerial imagery and orthophotography](https://www.linz.govt.nz/land/maps/aerial-imagery-and-orthophotography) and a range of cadastral information. The current map series is [Topo50](https://www.linz.govt.nz/land/maps/topographic-maps/topo50-maps), on a scale of 1:50,000, which covers the main islands of New Zealand and the Chatham Islands. Larger scale maps in the form of [Topo250](https://www.linz.govt.nz/land/maps/topographic-maps/topo250-maps) (1:250,000) are also available. Maps in digital format are freely available under Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International Licensing, and are available to download [here](https://www.linz.govt.nz/land/maps/linz-topographic-maps/map-chooser).  Large public libraries often contain collections of the more recent topographic maps as well as some older forms for free perusal and photocopying. Paper maps can be purchased from most book-stores and information points, as well as many outdoors stores. Some organizations, particularly hunting clubs also provide digital maps for free.

## South America

- **Peru**: http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/topo/peru/

Comment: UK: Harvey maps, while not government-level official, do have high-quality 25k and 1:40000 maps of the main mountain areas. The relative merits of OS and Harvey maps were a constant debate in my old hiking club.

In Switzerland, while swisstopo publishes both the 25k and 50k basemaps, they also have a "50T" (yellow) series at 1:50k that has all the official hiking trails marked in colour. But there's no "25T" equivalent from them on paper, hence various third parties fill this gap with the basemap licensed from swisstopo. I tend to buy these for mountain hikes in Switzerland.

Comment: @Bristol please, edit that in! UK and Switzerland were two of the countries I just scraped from the web...

Comment: Question for non-UK readers: I'm currently in the UK and if I go to maps.bing.com and zoom in over the UK, I can change the map type to OS to see an online version of the 25k/50k OS maps if I zoom in enough. Does this work from other countries - if so I'll add it to the wiki?

Comment: I don't think it works. I read about that, but couldn't find it (sitting in Finland, currently). [This post](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2009/11/12/released-bing-maps-uk/), while old, seems to support that.

Comment: I'll pause editing for now then :)

Comment: I'm finished, too. @Bristol, do you know whether the Swiss 25k and 50k series are congruent?

Comment: The 25k ones are pretty much exactly the quarters of the 50k ones, so yes (and there's 100k ones as well). But the 50k series also has a second layer of "composed" maps that are centered around regions of interest, and not congruent with the 25k ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76858/discussion-between-bristol-and-phg).

Comment: for belgium: [Nationaal Geografisch Instituut](http://www.ngi.be/NL/NL1-1.shtm)

Comment: Belgium (French): [Institut géographique national](http://www.ngi.be/FR/FR0.shtm)

Comment: @TobySpeight OSNI exists (maps are available in 1:50000, with a few of the more scenic regions in 1:25000 too). I think what wikipedia is saying is that it's now a department in a larger organisation.

Answer (score 2):

Denmark, including Faroe Islands and Greenland (also Sweden): [ScanMaps](https://www.scanmaps.dk)

Many different scales, ages and media as well as customized, personal maps printed and sent to you. Site is in Danish, but you can change to English.
The official government institution for Geo-data links to this (commercial) site for printed maps.

Topographic, Digital maps are available for download as TIFF images (for free); resolutions 1:25.000 - 1:1.000.0000 at [kortforsyningen.dk](https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/content/geodataprodukter?field_korttype_tid_1=439) (site is unfortunately only in Danish)

Comment: The idea is to add all answers to the community wiki answer instead of creating a dozen different ones

Comment: Maybe someone can do it for Dennis_DK, he is a new user after all.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing it into the community answer. Hope it is okay with you, Dennis.

Comment: Of course it is alright - thanks a bunch, Rasmus. And thanks for noticing that I'm a new user, Willeke - indeed, I did miss the answer being a CW, and the idea behind it.

Comment: Welcome Dennis_DK! I just want to add my thanks for joining us! We're glad our confusing rules didn't scare you off!  We have a good [help] for you to check out, but we encourage you to let us know if there's anything we can do to make it easier. Just drop a comment here, and, as you've noticed, someone will come along and help. We appreciate your contribution and hope to see more of you!

Comment: @Sue  anyone can suggest an edit

Comment: @Sue  your confusing being able to edit without having to get it reviewed and being able to edit by making a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

- **Italy**: [www.igmi.org/geoprodotti](https://www.igmi.org/geoprodotti)

I hope to add more details here and add it to the wiki once I try them out in practice shortly.

Comment: I added this link to the community answer. Any experiences to add? Where did you buy the map?

Comment: Thank you. I ended up leaving Italy before it became relevant. Maps were available to purchase online at that site.