# Where can I find free electronic topographic map that cover the entire West Coast Trail in Canada?

Tags: maps, canada, topographical-maps

Where can I find free electronic topographic map that cover the entire West Coast Trail in Canada? I'm trying to print them and bring them for my thru hike.

Comment: If this works https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/maps/9767 then we should close this as dupe of this one https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19254/official-providers-of-topographic-maps-per-country

Comment: That is descriptions to such maps nit the maps themselves. Where are the maps described there?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple options:

This guide is a general preparation and has good resources to save on a phone or something else, like phone numbers and general info, it also has a map, not detailed, but it does:

[Download Link](https://www.pc.gc.ca/-/media/pn-np/bc/pacificrim/WET4/visit/PDF/2018-wct-guide.pdf)

This is a better PDF from Parcs Canada to download and you can zoom using your electronic device (note: it is over 5mb):

[Trail map for West Coast Trail](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/bc/pacificrim/activ/~/media/62A0D8B48F4448F9B46C2BB8A0E092BB.ashx)