# How to find good hiking maps for the Laugavegur trail in Iceland?

Tags: hiking, navigation, maps, iceland

I will be hiking the Laugavegur trail alone and have been looking for good hiking maps (1:50 000) online. My google searches yield no good results. Where do you even begin to look?

Comment: Your answer is probably here: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/19254/3602

Comment: in case you won't find 1:50k, 1:100k is fine, especially if you will stick to the trail. I hiked that trail last year solo as well, and imho it's hard to get lost there.

Comment: also there are some Laugavegur 50:000 maps  on amazon

Comment: @robaki: Q: What do you do when you're lost in an Icelandic forest? A: Stand up.

Comment: To elaborate on the duplicate: there exists a Mál og Menning "Sérkort 4" specifically for Laugavegur (Landmannalaugar and Þórsmörk in 1:10000), which you get everywhere where you can buy maps in Reykjavík. Beware, it's not very waterproof ;)